# Node ARI Client | Connect method not firing callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asterisk-ari

So, I've started playing with the Asterisk Restful Interface (ARI).

I have created a separate express app to do this.

I have a correctly configured instance of Asterisk 13 running. I know this because When I go to `https://192.168.46.122:8088/ari/sounds` in my browser, I am prompted for a username and password, which when entered, returns a valid JSON object back with the expected data...

```
[
  {
    "id": "conf-now-unmuted",
    "text": "The conference is now unmuted.",
    "formats": [
      {
        "language": "en",
        "format": "gsm"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "vm-nomore",
    "text": "No more messages.",
    "formats": [
      {
        "language": "en",
        "format": "gsm"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "vm-review",
    "text": "press 1 to accept this recording press 2 to listen to it press 3 to rerecord your message",
    "formats": [
      {
        "language": "en",
        "format": "gsm"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "demo-echodone",
    "text": "The echo test has been completed.",
    "formats": [
      {
        "language": "en",
        "format": "gsm"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "confbridge-rest-talk-vol-out",
    "text": "...to reset your speaking volume to the default level.",
    "formats": [
      {
        "language": "en",
        "format": "gsm"
      }
    ]
  }, ...... etc etc
```

In my `app.js` file I have included the following code...

```
...
var logger = require('morgan');
var client = require('ari-client');
var url = 'https://192.168.46.122:8088/ari/sounds';
var username = 'correct_username';
var password = 'correct_password';

client.connect(url, username, password, function (err, ari) {
  console.log('HELLLLLLOOOOO!!');
});
...
```

The issue, is that the anon callback is never fired. I never see 'HELLLLLLOOOOO!!'

Can anyone shed any light on why/under what circumstances this could happen? Are there any known bugs with the module that could be causing this?

Please let me know if you need further information about config, environment etc.

Thanks guys

**UPDATE**

Following comments below... I have tried the following:

```
client.connect(url, username, password)
.then(function(ari) {
  console.log('HELLLLLLOOOOO!!');
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log('ERR: ' + err);
});
```

AND

```
client.connect(url, username, password, function (err, ari) {
  if(err) console.log(err);

  console.log('HELLLLLLOOOOO!!');
});
```

No error and no 'HELLLLLOOOOOO!!' at any point :-(

**UPDATE 2**

Have just visited `/ari/api-docs/resources.json` and got the following response... so it looks like it is present.

```
{
  "_copyright": "Copyright (C) 2012 - 2013, Digium, Inc.",
  "_author": "David M. Lee, II <dlee@digium.com>",
  "_svn_revision": "$Revision: 430337 $",
  "apiVersion": "1.7.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.1",
  "basePath": "http://192.168.46.122:8088/ari",
  "apis": [
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/asterisk.{format}",
      "description": "Asterisk resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/endpoints.{format}",
      "description": "Endpoint resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/channels.{format}",
      "description": "Channel resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/bridges.{format}",
      "description": "Bridge resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/recordings.{format}",
      "description": "Recording resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/sounds.{format}",
      "description": "Sound resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/playbacks.{format}",
      "description": "Playback control resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/deviceStates.{format}",
      "description": "Device state resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/mailboxes.{format}",
      "description": "Mailboxes resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/events.{format}",
      "description": "WebSocket resource"
    },
    {
      "path": "/api-docs/applications.{format}",
      "description": "Stasis application resources"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm now thinking it may be an SSL issue?!

Comment: can you try this `client.connect(url, username, password).then(function (ari) {}).catch(function (err) {console.log(err);});` it will help to see what is the error

Comment: In line with Khaled here, can you see if you're getting an error in the callback.  Above the console.log, write `if (err) console.error(err);`

Comment: This could also be the issue you're experiencing: https://github.com/asterisk/node-ari-client/issues/35

Comment: Thanks guys but see update on question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection is failing (for reasons outlined below), and because of an issue / upcoming-feature in `node-ari-client`, the failed connection is not logged.

The `node-ari-client` module uses [Swagger](http://swagger.io/), which expects to load a JSON schema describing an API. In the `node-ari-client` implementation, Swagger expects to find this JSON schema at `%s//%s/ari/api-docs/resources.json`.

So, the first thing to check is whether or not this exists / is accessible in your application:

`https://192.168.46.122:8088/ari/api-docs/resources.json`

There could be several reasons why this would not be available, but most likely the problem is authentication. You mention that when visiting your URL you are "*prompted for a username and password*". If your JSON schema (or any other files that need to be accessed without credentials) are behind authentication, you are going to need to rethink your application structure.

Currently, if there is a connection failure *before* Swagger has loaded the JSON schema, `node-ari-client` will fail silently. There is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/asterisk/node-ari-client/pull/12/files) waiting which addresses this issue and would log the error, but in the meantime you should address the underlying issues which are preventing the connection.

If you *can* successfully access `resources.json`, there may be other issues with accessing resources. The URL you describe is accessing your service over `https`, but your `resources.json` file is telling Swagger to access it over regular http. To handle this, you could try:

**Changing the `basePath` in your Swagger schema to use *https***:

`"basePath": "https://192.168.46.122:8088/ari",`

**Adding a `protocols` field to your Swagger schema:**
`"protocols":["http", "https"]`

**Removing https**
This is probably a good option in order to discover if `https` is the cause of the connection issue. Simply keep the Swagger schema exactly as is and try accessing / connecting to your services over `http`. Does this make a difference?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, greatly appreciated :) See 'Update 2' in my original post. Thanks

Comment: Nice work mate!! It's an SSL issue... the 100 rep is all yours ;-)

Comment: Side question: where can I find the Swagger schema? I haven't got Swagger installed as separate node module, I think it was just dragged in when I installed the ari-client?